# Angular 2 component variable scope and references

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to avoid always having to attach a "this" to referencing private Component variables or functions?

For example, the following will cause a "Cannot find name" error on "foo"

```
export class SomeComponent {
    private foo = 5;

    someMethod(){
        console.log(foo);
    }
}
```

To fix, I need to attach a "this" to the foo variable, as in:

```
console.log(this.foo);
```

I'm all for strong identification of variables, but this seems overly strict given the smaller size of most Angular components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `JavaScript` and `TypeScript` you need to refer to the fields and functions of the class in that class with the `this` keyword

**From The [Documentation of TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)**

Let’s take a look at a simple class-based example:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

The syntax should look familiar if you’ve used C# or Java before. We declare a new class Greeter. This class has three members: a property called greeting, a constructor, and a method greet.

**You’ll notice that in the class when we refer to one of the members of the class we prepend this.. This denotes that it’s a member access.**

Comment: Constructor shouldn't be considered a class member, isn't it?

Comment: it is a class member, but not field. I speak about the fields, and also functions. Constructor is also a `function` but you can't call it inside the same class with `this`.

Comment: I get that.  The problem I have is that I get ridiculous looking code that looks like  this.val = this.myMethod(this.variable1, this.variable2).   Personal preference I guess.  Thanks for clarifying though...

Comment: @MikeM I'm with Suren, it's not possible. Typescript has to implement classes this way because of scope isolation issues in javascript, if you don't specify the `this.gretting` you can accidentally access `window.gretting`. In coffeescript there's the `@gretting` prefix that means `this.gretting` maybe there is a equivalent feature for typescript.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro, thanks, that makes sense. It would be nice if the TypeScript transpileation would assume that locally declared variables and methods were scoped `this` if referenced internally in the class and other scopes (e.g. `window`) would require explicit declaration.

Comment: @MikeM I think it will never be like that :).Because I can use a top level defined variable in my class without this and it will cause problems

Comment: @SurenSrapyan but it's not just variables.  It's also all the methods in the class.   eh, I had similar style complaints moving from  Java to Obj-C.  :)

Comment: @MikeM would be nice if it could be done this way, but I'm not suer if it's possible, it must be transpiled with `this` to effort scope isolation. However there is this dilemma, what if I were trying to refere to a global variable? Therefore, the best aproach that could be done would be coffeescript's @gretting like members declaration.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I think the problem would only occur if the global variable/method had the same name as a variable/method in your class.  In other languages, this is something that the precompiler would normally flag.

Comment: That's not the problem i'm trying to explain. Typescript is not like compiled language, it is a javascript super set. Therfore it is limited by javascript